# ASP.NET - improve performance

Tags: asp.net, optimization

Is there any reason use standart HTML controls (input type=text,input type=checkbox) instead of asp.net controls ( asp:TextBox, asp:CheckBox)  to improve performance?

Answer (score 5):

IMHO this would be a micro optimization. You will gain performance but it won't be noticeable. On the other hand you will loose much of the flexibility offered by the server controls.

You could try to reduce the size of the ViewState by disabling it for controls that don't need it. This will reduce the size of the generated pages and improve performance.

Answer (score 4):

The ASP.NET user controls will all have ViewState associated with them unless you explicitly set

```
EnableViewState="False"
```

As such, you will bloat the size of the underlying page if you have a large number of controls. As a general rule, use what meets your needs and nothing more.

- Do you need to access the user control in the code-behind?
- Do you need the control to maintain value across post-backs etc?

In most cases, it won't make a difference, but it is good to keep your page clean if you don't need these features.

Answer (score 1):

As always with performance optimizations: it depends on the situation. Test it in your project and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Also with .net 4.0 another con of using server controls is gone, since you can set `ClientIDMode` to `Static`, which will give you full control over ID's on your controls. Previously using just a standard `textbox` or `button` (without `viewstate`) would still render crazy non-readable ID's because of the way Naming Containers work. Those days are over now though :)

Remember your three options are:

1. use regular html which can't be referenced on the server.
2. add `runat="server"` to your existing html-tags (ie. ) and you'll be able to access it as an `HtmlControl`.
3. use the asp.net tags (`<asp:* runat="server" />`)

The disadvantage of option 3 is that you don't always know what the rendered html-markup will be and you have less control over it. I personally only use option 3 for more advanced controls like , the button () and third party controls. For normal html-markup that I need to reference on the server I prefer option 2.

Regarding performance I would mainly look at the rendered output, how much extra bloat is rendered to the client and such. CPU-time on the server using one or the other approach I would say is secondary compared to the different caching techniques ASP.Net has already.